# NavigateUrl and EVAL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid, hyperlink, navigateurl

I am trying to Navigate URL 
in this way

```
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='javascript:NavigateUrl("<%#Eval("TicketID")%>","<%=RedirectURL %>");'><%# Eval("TicketID") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

but an error occurred in the javascript Error Console in Mozilla browser.

Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: javascript:NavigateUrl("<%#Eval("TicketID")%>","<%=RedirectURL%20%>");
Line: 1, Column: 22
Source Code:
NavigateUrl("<%#Eval("TicketID")%>","<%=RedirectURL %>");

I want to remove the error.
but functionality is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're in a repeater. The best way to do this would be to bind the hyperlink NavigateURL in the ItemDataBound event.

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HyperLink hyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hyperLinkid");
        hyperLink.NavigateURL = "url";
    }
}
```

That's very rough code but it's enough to give you a starting point!

Cheers, Sean

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:NavigateUrl('<%#Eval("TicketID")%>','<%=RedirectURL %>');"><%# Eval("TicketID") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

See that actual values of TicketID & RedirectURL are not being rendered.
asp:HyperLink is a server control. <%#...%> is a binding tag. is the control being databound?